# gradle zip part of dependencies, naming fileTree

Tags: dependencies, zip, gradle

I have some troubles, when trying to create zip archive containing project dependencies.
I have following dependency structure:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.7'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/', include: '*.jar') // I want this to be packed
    compile fileTree(dir: 'do_not_need_in_zip', include: '*.jar') // This must be excluded.
}
```

I'm trying to pack into archive only first two dependencies. But can't manage to filter them. I'm trying to do smth like this.

```
task dist(type: Zip, dependsOn ...) {
    from (project.configurations.compile.files { dep ->
    dep.name == 'groovy-all'
})
into 'lib'
}
```

But for `fileTree` dependencies name is unspecified, so, I can't filter this kind of dependency.

Maybe, I need save dependencies in variables, maybe smth. else. Can you give me an advice?

**EDIT:**
At this moment I have an array of dependencies to be added at archive, like this. It's dirty, but I think, working solution.

```
dependencies {
    distributionFiles.each{
        compile it
}   }
```

But @Rene 's answer looks more clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to split the configurations you're using. e.g. create a providedCompile configuration and assign the deps you don't want in your zip to that providedCompile configuration.